# I received products data from fakestoreapi to the console but not receiving to the browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, mern

I'm doing a amazon clone with next.js and fakestoreapi products data but Im not able to receive the data to the browser. but they receives to the vscode console. and I'm not even getting any error messages too. my code is as follows.

- index.js

```js
import Head from "next/head";
        import Header from "../src/Components/Header";
        import Banner from "../src/Components/Banner";
        import ProductFeed from "../src/Components/ProductFeed";
    
        export default function Home({ products }) {
          return (
            <div>
              <Head>
                <title>ShopBag | amazon Clone</title>
              </Head>
              <Header />
              <main className="max-w-screen-2xl bg-gray-100 mx-auto">
                {/* banner */}
                <Banner />
    
                {/* product Feild */}
    
                <ProductFeed products={products} />
              </main>
            </div>
          );
        }
        export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
          const products = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => console.log(json));
          return {
            props: {
              products: products || null,
            },
          };
        }
```

- ProductFeed.js

  ```
   import React from "react";
   import Product from "./Product";

   function ProductFeed({ products }) {
     return (
       <div>
         {products?.map(({ id, title, price, description, category, image }) => (
           <Product
             key={id}
             title={title}
             price={price}
             description={description}
             category={category}
             image={image}
           />
         ))}
       </div>
     );
   }
   export default ProductFeed;
  ```
- Product.js

  import React from "react";
  import Image from "next/image"

  ```
   function Product({ id, title, price, description, category, image }) {
     return (
       <div>
         <p>{category}</p>
         <Image src={image} height={200} width={200} objectfit="contain" alt="product-images" />
       </div>
     );
   }

   export default Product;
  ```
- next.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
    const nextConfig = {
      reactStrictMode: true,
      Images: {
        domains: ["./public", "fakestoreapi.com"],
        assetPrefix: isProd ? "/amazon-clone/" : "",
      },
    };

    module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you log the json in the second then, instead of returning it. You should do :

```
....
.then(json => json)
```

Or if you want to log it :

```
.then(json => {
   console.log(json)
   return json
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove then and use await

```
 const response = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
 const products = await response.json();
 return {
   props: {
     products: products || null,
   },
 };
```